# Years as a logarithmic scale on the x-axis with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, x-axis

I would like to plot dates on the x-axis using a logarithmic scale, such as in the example below, but I couldn't manage to get the correct spacing:

[image: plot]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scale is a logarithmic scale. The trick here is to consider the years as categories, not numbers. I used strings here for this effect.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': map(str, range(2010, 2045)), # years as strings
                   'value': 1 # dummy data here
                   })
ax = df.plot(x='year', y='value', marker='.')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xticks(range(1,35+1), rotation='vertical')  # categories start from 1
ax.set_xticklabels(df['year'])
```

output:

[image: matplotlib logarithmic scale years]